# Bumps from mites or something else?

Tags: dogs, health

[image]

My dog started becoming very itchy and had tiny bumps on her skin so we assumed she had mites like she had in the past , we are working on getting her into the vet but now recently she’s developed these bumps on both of her back legs , could this be from the mites or is it something else ?

Comment: Your best bet is to go to the vet.

Comment: Dear Niele, most people on this site are volunteers and no professional vets. Skin conditions like this are hard to diagnose from images alone. Even if one of us voiced any presumption, you'd most likely have to go to a vet to get a treatment. Because of that, we are reluctant to offer medical advice and refer you to consult a local vet anyways.